# How can I choose random values with specific criteria

Tags: php

I have to select random values from an array for each day of the month, but all values must be selected equally in the month. For this purpose I wrote the following code but I can not include the equality criteria.
Can you help me figure out how I can do this?

```
 <?php
$abc = array('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z');

$currentDate = date("Y-m-d", mktime(0, 0, 0, date("m"), date("d"), date("Y")));

$currentYear    = date("Y",strtotime($currentDate));
$currentMonth   = date("m",strtotime($currentDate));

$start_date     = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($currentYear.'-'.$currentMonth.'-01'));
$daysInMonth    = date('t',strtotime($start_date));
$emploeePerShift = 12;

$shiftsPerMonth = $daysInMonth * $emploeePerShift;

$shiftsPerEmploee   = (($shiftsPerMonth - ($shiftsPerMonth % count($abc))) / count($abc));
$extra_shifts       = $shiftsPerMonth % count($abc);

    
function _shift($pool, $start_date, $daysInMonth, $emploeePerShift){
    for($y=0;$y<$daysInMonth;$y++){
        $day  = date('Y-m-d', mktime(0, 0, 0, date('m',strtotime($start_date)), date('d',strtotime($start_date)) + $y, date('Y',strtotime($start_date))));
        $shift_val[$day]    = array_rand($pool, $emploeePerShift);
    }
    return $shift_val;
}

$test = _shift($abc, $start_date, $daysInMonth, $emploeePerShift);

var_dump($test);
?>
```

Comment: What is your goal? What you expect?

Comment: I need for the month all values to be equal selected $shiftsPerEmploee times